# Initialize two dimensional object array returns fatal error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to create a 2d array of teams. Therefore, I can reach with like Teams[0][i] or Teams[1][0]. First print returns correct value but second one returns fatal index out of range.

```
self.teams = [self.first_array , self.second_array]
print(self.teams[0][0].name)
print(self.teams[1][0].name)
```

Comment: Is `second_array` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
self.teams = [self.first_array , self.first_array]
```

If this works, then there's something wrong with self.second_array specifically.  Your syntax looks fine except we can't see the rest of the code, particularly where you're initializing self and its properties.